# Spring-Data LDAP missing some attributes

Tags: java, ldap, spring-data, spring-data-ldap

I have a Spring-Data LDAP repository configured as the following:

```java
public interface LdapUserRepository extends LdapRepository<LdapUser> {

  Set<LdapUser> findByNameLike(String name);

  Optional<LdapUser> findByAccount(String account);

  Optional<LdapUser> findByEmail(String email);

  Optional<LdapUser>  findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
}
```

Everything looks fine except by the fact that some attributes are being not fetched. For instance, I have an `employeeID` on LDAP user and being mapped on my LdapUser as the following:

```java
  @Attribute(name = "employeeID", readonly = true)
  private String document;
```

I've checked and it's correctly populated on my directory: 
[image]

When I query an User through (e.g) `Optional<LdapUser> findByAccount(String account)` almost everything comes populated except by `employeeID` mappend on `document` field.

I'm also able to fetch it by querying it through a non-spring-data way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after two months I finally found the answer.

As mentioned on these answers: [Get all attributes from Active Directory using Spring LdapTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49400714/3120564), https://stackoverflow.com/a/56839626/3120564, some attributes are not propagated to the GC by default. So I had to change the connection port from `3269` to `389` and set the `base` attribute on the `@Entry` annotation to something more specific (e.g. `OU=the_OU_I_want`).

This solved my problem.